# Advanced Average Date DIfference with unique ids

Tags: mysql, date, unique, average, datediff

im back to stack overflow with another headache that I have been trying to get to the bottom of with no success at all. No matter how many times I use avg(datediff) functions.

I have an SQL table like the below:

ID | PersonID | Start | End

1 | 1 | 2006-03-21 00:00:00  | 2007-05-19 00:00:00  | Active
2 | 1 | 2007-05-19 00:00:00  | 2007-05-20 00:00:00  | Active
3 | 2 | 2016-08-24 00:00:00  | 2016-08-25 00:00:00  | Active 
4 | 2 | 2005-08-25 00:00:00  | 2016-08-28 00:00:00  | Active 
5 | 2 | 2016-08-28 00:00:00  | 2017-10-05 00:00:00  | Active

Im trying to find the average active stay (in days) across all **unique** people.

Ie the average number of days based on their EARLIEST start date and LATEST end date (as a single person ID can have multiple active statuses).

For example, person ID 1, their earliest start date was 2006-03-21 and their latest end date is 2007-05-20. Their stay has therefore been 425 days.

Repeat this for ID number 2, their stay is 407 days.

After doing this for everyone on the table... I want to get the average length of stay, the average for the above 5 rows, with 2 unique people is 416. Doing a simple datediff average across all rows will give me a very inaccurate average of 102.

Hope this makes sense. As always,any help you could give is very much appreciated.

Comment: if you don't trust your result, sum the result of datediff and divide by number of aggregated values

Comment: I don't think that this is what he would like to do.

Comment: @iLikeMySql thanks for the very simple way of looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why not try that:

```
SELECT
  AVG(DATEDIFF(PersonEnd, PersonStart))
FROM
  (SELECT
     MIN(Start) AS PersonStart,
     MAX(End) AS PersonEnd
   FROM
     table
   GROUP BY
     PersonID) PeriodsPerPerson
```

Of course, you should have proper indexes so that MySQL can compute `MAX` and `MIN` fast and can group fast as well, which means indexes at least on `PersonID`, `Start` and `End`.

Please note that you really need the alias for the inner query although I don't use it anywhere. If you leave it away, you'll run into an error, at least with MySQL 5.5 (I don't know about later versions).

If you have millions or even billions of rows, you might be better off moving the calculation into a stored procedure or a back-end application instead of doing it as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for this, makes a lot of sense and seems to do exactly what I was looking for.